# change default sqlite database path in webkit while compilation

Tags: sqlite, compilation, webkit, arm

I am compiling webkit for an ARM target. Is there a way to change the default path where sqlite db is stored by webkit. can i hardcode it inside webkit?

I am getting this error right now:

```
ERROR: SQLite database failed to load from /.local/share/webkit/icondatabase/WebpageIcons.db
Cause - unable to open database file
Source/WebCore/platform/sql/SQLiteDatabase.cpp(70) : bool WebCore: QLiteDatabase: pen(const WTF: tring&, bool)
ERROR: Unable to open icon database at path /.local/share/webkit/icondatabase/WebpageIcons.db - out of memory
Source/WebCore/loader/icon/IconDatabase.cpp(990) : void* WebCore::IconDatabase::iconDatabaseSyncThread()
```

I want to change /.local/share/webkit/icondatabase/ to a different path where there are no read/write issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside webkit source in File ***Source/WebCore/loader/icon/IconDatabase.cpp***

Hard-coded database path as follows:

```
 m_databaseDirectory = "<your_dir_path>";
```

Worked fine for me.